# Querying simulation time in a plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
New to Gazebo, and I am trying to check the simulation time as part of my robot operation. Any advice on how to get started?

I have tried creating a common::Time object, which can get the wall time, but it doesn't have access to simulation time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2268/querying-simulation-time-in-a-plugin/) by [walkerbrianpatrick](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/299/walkerbrianpatrick/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

A plugin can access the World, which has a GetSimTime() function:
http://gazebosim.org/api/1.5.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html#ab767393cb972e31d86a3b935e3eed569

You can also subscribe to `~/world_stats` which publishes messages of type WorldStatistics:
http://gazebosim.org/msgs/1.5.0/world__stats_8proto.html

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1